# django smart_selects, second level won't populate

Tags: jquery, python, django, jquery-plugins

I can not get the second level (subcategory/E_cat) drop down to populate. First level (Category) seems to be working fine.  I think I've tried just about every reasonable combination of chained_field and chained_model_field selections without success.

I want the Equip table populate with the ID for the category and the ID for the subcategory.

Below is what the model currently looks like.  What am I doing wrong?

***model.py***

```
class Category(models.Model):
    cat_no = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    cat_txt = models.CharField(max_length=45)    
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.cat_txt

class E_cat(models.Model):
    cat_no = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    cat_txt = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    scat_no = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    scat_txt = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.scat_txt


class Equip(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    subcategory = ChainedForeignKey(
        E_cat,
        chained_field="category",
        chained_model_field="cat_no",
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True,
    )
    manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=True)
    mfg_no = models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=True)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=True)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=True)
    quanity = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    short_description = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True)
    location_zip = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    listings = models.ForeignKey(Listings)
    info = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [django smart-selects from ManytoManyField to ChainedForeignKey how to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919623/django-smart-selects-from-manytomanyfield-to-chainedforeignkey-how-to)

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE - MAY 2017**

include this tag right after jQuery version 2 . It works perfrectly well in Django 1.10 and 1.11 version using python 3.5.2. 
Hope this helps you

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'smart-selects/admin/js/chainedfk.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'smart-selects/admin/js/chainedm2m.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'smart-selects/admin/js/bindfields.js' %}"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks alright.  The problem might be that you haven't set up the smart_selects urls, or perhaps you're missing the javascript in your actual page.

Comment: I do have urls setup, and app installed.  I did not see any javascript that I had to include on my template!  If that is necessary this cold be the problem.  I'll go take a look at the docs/readme again.

Comment: You need a tag in the template so that the javascript shows up.  Assuming the name of your form variable is `form`, you probably already have `{{ form }}` somewhere in your template.  I believe you need to add `{{ form.media.js }}` somewhere in your template as well so that the Javascript gets inserted into your page.

Answer (score 0):

**html.file**

include the following if you are using forms

```
<script src="{% static 'smart-selects/admin/js/chainedfk.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'smart-selects/admin/js/chainedm2m.js' %}"></script>
```

**models.py**

```
class Continent(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

    class Country(models.Model):
        continent= models.ForeignKey(Continent)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

    class City(models.Model):
        continent= models.ForeignKey(Continent)
        country= ChainedForeignKey(Country, chained_field="continent",  chained_model_field="continent", show_all=False, auto_choose=True, sort=True)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

    class Neighborhood(models.Model):
        continent= models.ForeignKey(Continent)
        country= ChainedForeignKey(Country, chained_field="continent",  chained_model_field="continent", show_all=False, auto_choose=True, sort=True)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        city= ChainedForeignKey(City, chained_field="country",  chained_model_field="country", show_all=False, auto_choose=True, sort=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
```

**admin.py**

```
admin.site.register(Component)
admin.site.register(Group)
admin.site.register(Failure)
admin.site.register(Neighborhood)
```