# django smart-selects app

Tags: jquery, python, django, jquery-plugins

I'm having a problem getting the django "smart-selects" app to function properly. It will not populate the select for my chained field. The "readme" file on github "https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects" gives the following instructions.

- The chained field is the field on the same model the field should be chained too.
- The chained model field is the field of the chained model that corresponds to the model linked too by the chained field.

I find the instructions a little cryptic, and they do not show the model for the Continent and County tables, to make it easier.

I have a previous question posted regarding this which I did not get a response to.  It has more info about my specific model.  "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155350/django-smart-selects-second-level-wont-populate"

Hopefully there are some "django-smart-selects" experts that can get me over the hump.  Thanks

```
from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedForeignKey 

class Location(models.Model)
    continent = models.ForeignKey(Continent)
    country = ChainedForeignKey(
        Country, 
        chained_field="continent",
        chained_model_field="continent", 
        show_all=False, 
        auto_choose=True
    )
    area = ChainedForeignKey(Area, chained_field="country", chained_model_field="country")
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should insert this in the urls.py:

url(r'^chaining/', include('smart_selects.urls')),

This is what I did and worked:

```
#=================================
#models.py

from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedForeignKey 

class Continent(models.Model):
    continent = models.CharField(max_length = 45)    
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.continent)

class Country(models.Model):
    continent = models.ForeignKey(Continent)
    country = models.CharField(max_length = 45)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.country)

class Area(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
    area = models.CharField(max_length = 45)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.area)

class Location(models.Model):
    continent = models.ForeignKey(Continent)
    country = ChainedForeignKey
    (
        Country, 
        chained_field = "continent", 
        chained_model_field = "continent", 
        show_all = False, auto_choose = True
    )
    area = ChainedForeignKey(Area, chained_field = "country", chained_model_field = "country")
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    street = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

#=================================
#admin.py


from yourapp.models import Continent
from yourapp.models import Country
from yourapp.models import Area
from yourapp.models import Location


class ContinentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

class CountryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

class AreaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

class LocationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(Continent, ContinentAdmin)
admin.site.register(Country, CountryAdmin)
admin.site.register(Area, AreaAdmin)
admin.site.register(Location, LocationAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the given example of for country = ChainedForeignKey() field, the chained_field="continent" refers to the "continent" field in Location class.  The chained_model_field="continent" refers to a "continent" field inside the Country model (which is not shown in the example).

Comment: That is the way I had interpreted it also.  But, it is not working.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but yes, the Country class needs to have a ForeignKey to the Continent, Area needs a ForeignKey to Country, City needs a ForeignKey to Area, etc down the chain.

Answer (score 0):

That is the way I interpreted it dragonx.  But I am obviously missing something.

I am thinking the other classes look like this

```
class Continent(models.Model):
    continent = models.CharField(max_length=45)    
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.continent

class Country(models.Model):
    continent = models.ForeignKey(Continent)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.county
```

with "continent" in the Country class being an integer field that corresponds to the ID field of the Continent class (ForeignKey/field) upon which the join is made.  Is this the way you see it?