# Django smart select not working

Tags: python, django

I have imported django smart select and have a model named `Request` in which field `assigned_to` and `approval_by` should have dynamic choices.There are no errors from `makemigrations` or `migrate` but dynamic choices dropdown isn't working for `assigned_to`. In fact, the dropdown for `assigned_to` is not showing any choice. What could be the cause?

Here's `models.py`:

```
from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedForeignKey

class Department(models.Model):
  department_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.department_name

class UserProfile(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User)
  user_department = models.ForeignKey("Department")

  def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username

class SuperUser(models.Model):
  superuser = models.OneToOneField(User,limit_choices_to={'is_superuser':True},unique=True)
  head_department = models.ForeignKey("Department")

  def __str__(self):
          return self.superuser.username

class Request(models.Model):
      # user = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True,related_name="user")
      department = models.ForeignKey("Department")
      request_type = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=typechoices)
      priority=models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=prioritychoices)
      description = models.TextField()
      sample = models.FileField(storage=fs,blank=True,null=True)
      approval_flag = models.BooleanField(default=False)
      status = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=statuschoices,default='pending')
      created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True)
      modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
      assigned_to = ChainedForeignKey(UserProfile,blank=True,null=True,chained_field="department",chained_model_field="user_department",show_all=False)
      approval_by = ChainedForeignKey(SuperUser,related_name="apprby",blank=True,null=True,chained_field="department",chained_model_field="head_department",show_all=False)

      def __str__(self):
          return str(self.id)
```

Comment: I changed attribute show_all = True as well but it still show empty dropdown.What could be problem its not showing even single choice even of another department

Comment: try - models.ForeignKey(Department)

Comment: does giving quotes matter while taking foreign key

Comment: does anyone have any other method to give dynamic choices ,Django_smart_select sucks .why the hell create such pluggins which don't work

Comment: @MrinalMahajan: [Here's the documentation for django-smart-selects](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects#chained-selects). I'm not gonna guess how you expect your ChainedForeignKey fields to work, but I suspect you'll have more success if you follow the documented usage.

Comment: Chained Foreign Key is still same but Grouped Foreign key work though it shows all the groups. Is there a way i can show only a particular group using it

Comment: check my example here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155350/django-smart-selects-second-level-wont-populate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155350/django-smart-selects-second-level-wont-populate)

Answer (score 4):

Its because of the branch master, I think it doesn't have stable code. 
I tried with js-unlinting-fixes branch and it worked.

just do following and it will start working

```
pip uninstall django-smart-selects
pip install  git+https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects.git@js-unlinting-fixes
```

Happy coding...