# Chained Selects in Django [Module: django-smart-selects]

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-smart-selects

I'm trying to use the django-smart-selects Module in order to create dependent dropdown lists. I've followed the documentation and defined models in which I used the 'ChainedForeignKey' in order to define a link between my companies and my products.

**models.py**

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Product(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Rates(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = ChainedForeignKey(
        Product,
        chained_field = "company",
        chained_model_field = "company",
        show_all = False,
        auto_choose = True,
        sort=True)
     taux_comm_1 = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(1)])
     taux_comm_2 = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(1)])
```

Then I have defined a form :

**forms.py**

```
class Rates(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Rates
        fields= ['company', 'product', 'taux_comm_1', 'taux_comm_2']
```

The data is retrieved from my database and I can select a company from the first dropdown list. The second list (Product), though, is locked. I've associated products to companies in my database ( using the foreign key ).

If you guys have any ideas how I could solve that problem, that would be really good. I've searched for a similar issue but I couldn't find anything like it.

Here is a screenshot of the form.

[image: Here is a screenshot of the form]

Comment: Here is the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/52361037/3472881 Happy coding

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used JS Lint brach (https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects/tree/js-unlinting-fixes) and it solved the issue.

Reference : https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects/issues/258

**EDIT: Adding step by step instructions to address the issue:**

**Step 1:** Remove existing version of django-smart-selects. Type `pip uninstall django-smart-selects` in the terminal.

**Step 2:** Install the JS-lint branch by typing

```
pip install git+https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects.git@js-unlinting-fixes`
```

**Step 3:** Add `'smart_selects',` to the `INSTALLED_APPS` list in `settings.py`.

**Step 4:** Add `from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedForeignKey` in `models.py` of your app.

**Step 5:** Add the `smart_selects` urls into your project's `urls.py`. This is needed for the `Chained Selects` and `Chained ManyToMany` selects. For example:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^chaining/', include('smart_selects.urls')),
)
```

**Step 6:** You will also need to include jQuery in every page that includes a field from `smart_selects`. Add `USE_DJANGO_JQUERY = True` in your project's `settings.py`.

**Step 7:** Add `{{ form.media.js }}` just before `{{ form.as_table }}` in your HTML file so that your Django form derived from the Django model reflects the smart-selects features.

I'm using Python 2.7.10 and Django 1.11.

All the best!

Comment: [Vidal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5076666/vidal) would like to ask: I am facing exactly the same issue. Tried many seemingly "correct" replies but did not fit my case. Almost gave up thinking this might be a compatibility issue when I came across this question. What I am asking from you is : Could you please let me know **what exactly you did** to overcome the problem?

Comment: I uninstalled the master version of django-smart selects (https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects) which I initially had and then installed the JS lint branch (https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects/tree/js-unlinting-fixes).

Comment: Following this, add 'smart_selects' in settings.py and add 'from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedForeignKey' in  models.py. Use ChainedForeignKey as illustrated in the question.

Comment: You need to add {{ form.media.js }} before your form in the HTML file in order to use smart-selects in HTML.

Comment: @SmitKamal How about rather adding the explanations into your answer and delete the comments?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard: Done ! :)